# Why is OpenXava not recognizing my Pojo?

Tags: openxava

I am using openxava 4.7.1 with MySQL. I have made all the right configurations and defined my pojos like this one for example

package com.iserve.ticketmanager;

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.openxava.annotations.*;

@Entity
public class Party {

    @Id
    @Required
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = true)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 45, nullable = true)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "manager", nullable = true)
    private Integer manager;

    @Stereotype("IMAGE")
    @Column(name = "logo", nullable = true)
    private String logo;

    @Column(name = "active", length = 0, nullable = true)
    private Boolean active;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Payment> payment;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<User> user;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Ticketsale> ticketsale;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Vendorcontract> vendorcontract;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Inventory> inventory;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Ticketredeem> ticketredeem;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Ticket> ticket;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Shipment> shipment;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Ticketbatch> ticketbatch;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Route> route;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Vehicle> vehicle;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Ticketdenomination> ticketdenomination;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Vendororder> vendororder;

    public void setId(Integer aValue) {
        id = aValue;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String aValue) {
        name = aValue;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setManager(Integer aValue) {
        manager = aValue;
    }

    public Integer getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setLogo(String aValue) {
        logo = aValue;
    }

    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean aValue) {
        active = aValue;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setPayment(Set<Payment> aValue) {
        payment = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Payment> getPayment() {
        return payment;
    }

    public void setUser(Set<User> aValue) {
        user = aValue;
    }

    public Set<User> getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setTicketsale(Set<Ticketsale> aValue) {
        ticketsale = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Ticketsale> getTicketsale() {
        return ticketsale;
    }

    public void setVendorcontract(Set<Vendorcontract> aValue) {
        vendorcontract = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Vendorcontract> getVendorcontract() {
        return vendorcontract;
    }

    public void setInventory(Set<Inventory> aValue) {
        inventory = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Inventory> getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public void setTicketredeem(Set<Ticketredeem> aValue) {
        ticketredeem = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Ticketredeem> getTicketredeem() {
        return ticketredeem;
    }

    public void setTicket(Set<Ticket> aValue) {
        ticket = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Ticket> getTicket() {
        return ticket;
    }

    public void setShipment(Set<Shipment> aValue) {
        shipment = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Shipment> getShipment() {
        return shipment;
    }

    public void setTicketbatch(Set<Ticketbatch> aValue) {
        ticketbatch = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Ticketbatch> getTicketbatch() {
        return ticketbatch;
    }

    public void setRoute(Set<Route> aValue) {
        route = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Route> getRoute() {
        return route;
    }

    public void setVehicle(Set<Vehicle> aValue) {
        vehicle = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
        return vehicle;
    }

    public void setTicketdenomination(Set<Ticketdenomination> aValue) {
        ticketdenomination = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Ticketdenomination> getTicketdenomination() {
        return ticketdenomination;
    }

    public void setVendororder(Set<Vendororder> aValue) {
        vendororder = aValue;
    }

    public Set<Vendororder> getVendororder() {
        return vendororder;
    }
}
```

I start the application by starting tomcat in the openxava distribution. When I try to access any module, i get error similar to this in all cases -

```
un 04, 2013 7:40:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet module threw exception
org.openxava.util.XavaException: Seems that party is not an EJB3 Entity nor transient model class
    at org.openxava.annotations.parse.AnnotatedClassParser.getClassNameFor(AnnotatedClassParser.java:2415)
    at org.openxava.annotations.parse.AnnotatedClassParser.parse(AnnotatedClassParser.java:66)
    at org.openxava.component.ComponentParser.parseAnnotatedClass(ComponentParser.java:47)
    at org.openxava.component.ComponentParser.parse(ComponentParser.java:36)
    at org.openxava.component.MetaComponent.get(MetaComponent.java:60)
    at org.openxava.component.MetaComponent.exists(MetaComponent.java:75)
    at org.openxava.application.meta.MetaApplication.existsModel(MetaApplication.java:151)
    at org.openxava.application.meta.MetaApplication.getMetaModule(MetaApplication.java:140)
    at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.getMetaModule(ModuleManager.java:1058)
    at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.setupModuleControllers(ModuleManager.java:244)
    at org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.setModuleName(ModuleManager.java:1031)
    at org.apache.jsp.xava.module_jsp._jspService(module_jsp.java:166)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.openxava.web.servlets.ModuleServlet.doGet(ModuleServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

What could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're using lowercase for the first letter of the entity in the URL. Try the URL in this way:

```
http://localhost:8080/YourApplication/modules/Party
```

YourApplication and Party cases must be the correct ones.